# Crusader Kings 2: How to extract character religion from saved game?

Tags: crusader-kings-2-modding

I am trying to parse and interpret the Crusader Kings 2 save file. I run into problem when trying to extract character religion.

```
3185293=
{
    bn="Umar"
    b_d="1543.12.21"
    fat=3160797
    mot=3160268
    att={7 3 4 3 3}
    tr={195 }
    rel="norse_pagan_reformed"
    cul="andalusian_arabic"
    dnt=1000128972
    dna="xvfudvhjgxg"
    prp="ojcf0k00000000000000000000000000000000"
    fer=0.400
    health=5.100
    # ... shortened ...
}
```

In many cases, trait **rel** is missing. In the [documentation](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Save-game_editing#Characters), I found reference that the trait *does not appear if government make it unnecessary*. Can you please advise how exactly to extract character religion if the trait is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The doc you linked seems to have the answer: look it up from the government.

> rel # religion – does not appear if government make it unnecessary, 
> e.g. if muslim_government and religion is sunni

So, you can make a table of key-value pairs, matching each government type to its default religion. If the `rel` trait is missing, take the `gov` trait and use it to look up the corresponding default religion from your table to substitute for the elided trait.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are probably right. But how to assign the religion according to the government? In the [government list](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Government#List_of_government_types) I do not see such assignment. The feudal_government could be easily Christian, Christian Heresy or Reformed Norse Pagan. Also [here](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Government_modding).

Comment: Generate lots of save files with different government/religion pairings. Then inspect the results. Some of the combinations will include the `rel` trait: those ones are non-default pairings. Some of the combinations will *not* include the `rel` trait: that reveals which religion was considered by the game to be the default for that government type.